# What Australian visa is required?

Tags: australia, uk-citizens, working-visas

What is the visa required for a British citizen coming to Australia for 10 days to perform mechanical work? He is employed by a UK firm.

Comment: Who pays the visitor?

Comment: What sort of mechanical work?  Why can't it be done by someone already in Australia?  If it requires highly specialised skills/knowledge/experience that can't be found within Australia, then a [Temporary Work (Short Stay Specialist) visa (subclass 400)](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/400-) would appear the most appropriate.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify, putting on hold as unclear